# Are duplicate math operations reran in case expressions?

Tags: sql, sql-server

In the example below, does the sql execution do anything to "cache" the results of fuel + cost? Or does the math get ran potentially three times? This is not a real use case, I just drummed up this example to mimic a more realistic need.

```
select case when shipFuelSurcharge + shipCost > 0
                        then 'over'
                    when shipFuelSurcharge + shipCost < 0
                        then 'under'
                    when shipFuelSurcharge + shipCost = 0
                        then 'equals'
            end as ExampleMathCase
    from shipment
```

Comment: What is the more realistic need? Databases don't just execute SQL queries, they convert them to execution plans that use specific indexing, scanning strategies, caching of data etc. Logically equivalent queries usually result in identical execution plans even if the syntax is different. IO is more expensive than simple additions too, so the performance of *this* `CASE` clause shouldn't have a detectable impact

Comment: The requirement is very similar to the example, per record, I need to evaluate a math equation, if the result is higher than a given number, select the result of that math + another variable, otherwise only return the math.

essentially, I am trying to figure out if it would be better to pull this logic out of sql all together... if it would be more efficient

Comment: Post the actual query, don't describe it. IO is much more expensive than 3 additions - orders of magnitude more expensive. If you really need to see what's going on, inspect the actual execution plan. There will  be a `Compute Scalar` node that calculates the value. Whatever that expression is though, it probably *doesn't* affect performance - again, just reading a row is 100-1000 times slower than an ADD operation. So is sending results over the network.

Comment: There are certainly some expressions that cause the data engine to rerun said expression. A (poorly written) expression like `CASE (SELECT TOP (1) a FROM dbo.SomeTable) WHEN 1 THEN (SELECT TOP (1) a FROM dbo.SomeTable) END` would likely result in the subquery being run twice, and because there is no `ORDER BY` it could even mean that the `CASE` expression returns a value other than `1` or `NULL`.

Comment: Panagiotis, the query I want to show is within a much larger query, would be difficult to show here. I am unable to run query plans at my company. 

But I think you've answered my question. I appreciate the discussion.

Comment: The very fact it's inside a larger query is *very* relevant. The operation itself won't affect performance *BUT* if you try to filter, group or order by it, the server will be forced to at least store the intermediate results locally. Database servers accelerate queries by using indexes built from field values. They can't use those indexes when you filter/group on function results. This forces them to scan all rows to calculate the values.

Comment: If you have a lot of rows (hundreds of thousands or more) and complex calculations it may be better to use a computed and persisted column, effectively precalculating the value on save. You can even index persisted computed columns.

Comment: I tested this query with a table variable, using both this `CASE` expression *and* a subquery to "precalculate" the sum. In both cases the execution plan is exactly the same, and the `Compute Scalar` operation in both cases is `Scalar Operator(CASE WHEN ([shipFuelSurcharge]+[shipCost])>(0.0000) THEN 'over' ELSE CASE WHEN ([shipFuelSurcharge]+[shipCost])<(0.0000) THEN 'under' ELSE CASE WHEN ([shipFuelSurcharge]+[shipCost])=(0.0000) THEN 'equals' ELSE NULL END END END)`. The relative cost of the operator compared to the table scan is 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question can't be answered without knowing what the *actual* query is. The database doesn't execute SQL queries in the way they're written. The query optimizer will simplify and optimize them, then create an execution plan based on the table schemas, indexes *and* data statistics. The expensive part is reading the data from disk, not calculating simple additions and comparison.

For example, these two queries have the same execution plan and cost the same as far as the query optimizer is concerned:

```
declare @shipment table(id int primary key,shipFuelSurcharge numeric(18,4), shipCost numeric(18,4))

select case when shipFuelSurcharge + shipCost > 0
                        then 'over'
                    when shipFuelSurcharge + shipCost < 0
                        then 'under'
                    when shipFuelSurcharge + shipCost = 0
                        then 'equals'
            end as ExampleMathCase
from  @shipment;

select case when valuesum > 0
                        then 'over'
                    when valuesum < 0
                        then 'under'
                    when valuesum = 0
                        then 'equals'
            end as ExampleMathCase
from  (select shipFuelSurcharge + shipCost  as valuesum from @shipment) x
```

[image: Comparison of alternate expressions shows they have the same execution plan]

The scalar calculation is the same in both cases.

```
[Expr1003] = Scalar Operator(CASE WHEN ([shipFuelSurcharge]+[shipCost])>(0.0000) THEN 'over' 
    ELSE CASE WHEN ([shipFuelSurcharge]+[shipCost])<(0.0000) THEN 'under' 
    ELSE CASE WHEN ([shipFuelSurcharge]+[shipCost])=(0.0000) THEN 'equals' 
    ELSE NULL END END END)
```

Execution plans work on streams of rows and precalculating the sum would require another node in the flow. That doesn't mean the actual expression doesn't get simplified either by the engine or the CPU though.

The relative cost for *this* expression is 0, because the IO cost is far greater than a few float additions and comparison.

Things are different if the actual query uses the operation result for filtering, ordering or grouping. The server can't use any indexes to accelerate the query and has to calculate the expression results first before proceeding.

This query results in a more complex and expensive execution plan :

```
declare @shipment table(id int primary key,shipFuelSurcharge numeric(18,4), shipCost numeric(18,4))


select ExampleMathCase,count(*)
from (
    select case when shipFuelSurcharge + shipCost > 0
                        then 'over'
                    when shipFuelSurcharge + shipCost < 0
                        then 'under'
                    when shipFuelSurcharge + shipCost = 0
                        then 'equals'
            end as ExampleMathCase
    from  @shipment) xx 
group by ExampleMathCase;


select case when shipFuelSurcharge + shipCost > 0
                        then 'over'
                    when shipFuelSurcharge + shipCost < 0
                        then 'under'
                    when shipFuelSurcharge + shipCost = 0
                        then 'equals'
            end as ExampleMathCase
from  @shipment;
```

The more complex query is considered almost 5 times more expensive:

[image: Grouping on the result is far more expensive]